# php check for matches in txt file

Tags: php

Hi im creating a simple log in system. I'm aware the way im doing is completely unsafe but its just for learning purposes, since im new to php. I'm having trouble with the validation, right now its not reporting if the username or password exists in the txt file. I also gonna use sessions(not fully implemented) to keep track if a user is logged in or not.

```
         <?php 
      session_start(); // session


       if(isset($_POST['register'])) //  Register USER
    {
      $user  = $_POST['username'];
      $password=$_POST['password'].PHP_EOL;
      $fh = fopen("file.txt","a+");
      fwrite($fh,$user." ".$password); //write to txtfile
      fclose($fh);
    }
```

The output in the txt file looks like this:

```
      user1 password1
      user2 password2
```

This is where i need help

```
      if(isset($_POST['Login']))
      {
      $_SESSION['username']=$user; 
  $_SESSION['password']=$password;

  $file = file_get_contents("file.txt");



 if (strpos($file, "$user $password".PHP_EOL) !== false) 
  {
     // go to login page
  }
  else 
{ 
     //ERROR
}

    ?>
```

Comment: NEVER, EVER store passwords in plain text NOR in a text file accessable through the document root!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`file_get_contents()` takes a filename, not a file pointer, so you should use `file_get_contents('file.txt')` and get rid of the `fopen` call.

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file-get-contents.php

Then, the value of `$file` is a string containing all the contents of the file as a single string.  So you can use normal string operations and don't need any of that `feof` stuff.

However you may want to look at `file()`, it is probably useful to you:

http://php.net/manual/en/function.file.php

EDIT:

You also have a problem with your logic.

You are checking the username first and then the password as a separate operation.  This will match *any* user with *any* user's password.  Let's say we have users alice with password "foo", and bob with password "bar", well with the current logic, alice will be able to login with either "foo" or "bar" as password.

So what you are actually looking for is a single string which is the concatenation of the username and the password, as it is found in the file (e.g. `"alice foo".PHP_EOL`):

```
if (strpos($file, "$user $password".PHP_EOL) !== false) {
    // go to login page
} else {
    // error
}
```

The reason you need the `PHP_EOL` in there is that this is what you have used to mark the end of the record.  If you don't put it in the search string, then you will match any substring of the real password, including an empty password.  (The file contains the text `"alice foo".PHP_EOL` and it contains the text `"alice "` but it does not contain the text `"alice ".PHP_EOL`).

Comment: I've updated the code according to your suggestions.Validation is still not working

Comment: Still not reporting if the username or passowrd is incorrect. Maybe I need to split up the string ($results = explode(" ", $file); and then check if 0 and 1 are equal to username and password.

Answer (score 1):

The problem is here:

```
$fp = fopen ("file.txt", "r"); // read from file
$file = file_get_contents($fp);
```

Using `fopen` you can read the file line by line and using `file_get_contents` you get the entire file contents as a string by specifying the file name as argument not a file handle.

You have mixed up both.

Comment: Thanks you for clearing that up. I've updated the code but the the same problem still remains.

Answer (score 1):

php variables inside quotes will act like only string
 $_SESSION['username']="$user";
use it like this  $_SESSION['username']=$user;

Answer (score 0):

since you are learning, I won't give you code, but can give you logic
explode through "\n"
then explode the result array value through space

check if that array values 0 and 1 are equal to username and password, if same then success

Still have any doubts feel free to ask

Comment: I'll give that a try and report back to you if i get stuck=)

Comment: Does this look correct    $result = explode("\n",$file);              foreach($result as $one)
     {
    $results = explode(" ",$one);  // explode through space
    print_r($results);
     }