# check if email exsite in txt file using PHP

Tags: php, file, text

I'm using this code to check if the entered email is existe or not in text file

```
$handle = fopen("http://mywebsite/u.txt", "r");
if ($handle) {
    while (($line = fgets($handle)) !== false) {
        $line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line);
        if($line=$email){
            echo "email existe";
        }
    }

    fclose($handle);
} else {
    // error opening the file.
}
```

the output is the same for exsiting emails and not exsiting email in the text file

> email existeemail existeemail existe

the text file contains as a test emails

- test@test.com
- hello@world.com
- test@t.com

if i did == it didn't enter the condition when the $line = $email

trying with

```
echo $line." ".$email;
```

OUTPUT

> test@test.com test@test.comtest@test.com test@test.comtest@test.com
>   test@test.com

Comment: Good code indentation would help us read the code and more importantly it will help **you debug your code**
[Take a quick look at a coding standard](http://www.php-fig.org/psr/psr-2/) for your own benefit. You may be asked to amend this code
in a few weeks/months and you will thank me in the end.

Comment: `if($line=$email)` < is an assignment and will always be TRUE. You're looking for `if($line==$email)` with an extra `=`. Give that a try. If it works, there's a duplicate for this.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i tried that but the problem of == is that is not enter inside the if condition when the $line is equal to the $email

Comment: *"and i have a second question"* - That makes your question too broad. One question at a time please.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner sorry about that, i deleted it
also please check my upated question

Comment: You might need to `trim()` both the line and the email to make sure there's no whitespace/new lines

Comment: @aynber i did `$line = preg_replace('/\s+/', ' ', $line);` is that not enough ?

Comment: No worries @user11845248 To answer that though, you can place that file outside the public area and somewhere under a hidden folder in the root, just outside the public folder.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner i'm accessing that file from different server, so how can i access it if it's not in public folder? is that possible?

Comment: No, it's not enough, because when I run your code but put `var_dump($line);` after your preg_replace, it still has a space after it.

Comment: Actually, your preg_replace is messing it up. You're replacing all spaces with a single space. It should be `$line = preg_replace('/\s+/', '', $line);`

Comment: Thank you so much @aynber that worked, i did trim for `$line` and `$email`

Comment: Hm.... now that complicates things then. If you can `.htaccess`, you can allow only your server to access the file and not let anyone else get access. [See this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42381048/1415724) and [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/409496/1415724) which could be of help. And you're welcome :) Glad to know things worked out.

Comment: @aynber I'd place an answer for what you suggested and add the fact about the missing `=` sign. This one's yours if you want it.

Comment: wow, didn't think of that, i will try that and open a question if it didn't worked the way i like

Comment: @user11845248 Seeing someone posted an answer that doesn't really outline the problems that prohibited your code to work properly, decided to post an answer myself instead.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner thanks for adding it. I’d stepped away from the computer for awhile

Comment: @aynber You're welcome. Oh, I didn't know. Gave you kudos on it and something else earlier :-) *Cheers!*

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your code failed for 2 reasons.

1) `if($line=$email)` is an assignment method and will always be TRUE. You were looking to use the `==` comparison method.

2) You need to use `trim()` since that will take care of new line characters that are getting included in your file. This was outlined by another member here, being [Aynber](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1007220/aynber). Kudos to them.

Per:

> *"You might need to trim() both the line and the email to make sure there's no whitespace/new lines – aynber"*.

and

> *"put var_dump($line); after your preg_replace, it still has a space after it."*

Comment: i've find out that it work only for the first line, test@test.com but for hello@world.com
 it don't work, i need to do foreach..., how can i do that please

Comment: @user11845248 Oh I see. Why do you need to do a `foreach` though?

Comment: @user11845248 Have a look at [this Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/36808229/1415724)  and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15154011/1415724) and [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/q/15189470/1415724). Maybe there's something in one of those that will help fix the new problem you're having. I found those when Googling "if user password exists in file php -mysql". The `-` before "mysql" in Google means to "not include mysql".

Answer (score 1):

I don't know if I understood you correctly, but here you have a slightly different solution to the problem

```php
// File from http
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, "https://example.com");
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
$handle = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);   

// or
$handle = file_get_contents("u.txt");
//or
$handle = "test@test.com \n hello@world.com";


$find = "hello@world.com";

if (strpos($handle, $find) > -1){ 
    echo "Found" ; 
} else{ 
    echo "Not Found"; 
}
```

Comment: This is probably faster than looping line by line. But even if it works, I'm not sure I like the `>-1` thing. Strpos returns false if nothing is found. Make it `!== false`